# How not to change url when show 404 error page with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to show 404 error page, but also I want to save wrong url in location.

If I'll do something like that:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('404');
$stateProvider
    .state('404', {
        url: '/404',
        template: error404Template
    });
```

url will change to `/404`. How I can show error message on wrong urls without changing actual url?

Answer (score 39):

There is solution for this scenario. We'd use 1) one `ui-router` native feature and 2) one configuration setting. A [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xtvKDVdYTK8h1ENrxdFY?p=preview) could be observed [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xtvKDVdYTK8h1ENrxdFY?p=preview).

1) A native feature of ui-router state definitions is:

> The `url` is not needed. State could be defined without its representation in location.

2) A configuration setting is:

- [`otherwise()` for invalid routes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes), which parameter does not have to be a string with default url, but could be a function as well *(cite)*:

> path **String | Function** The url path you want to redirect to or a function rule that returns the url path. The function version is passed two params: $injector and $location

**Solution:** combination of these two. We would have `state` **without** `url` and custom `otherwise`:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('404', {
    // no url defined
    template: '<div>error</div>',
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
   var state = $injector.get('$state');
   state.go('404');
   return $location.path();
});
```

Check that all in this [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xtvKDVdYTK8h1ENrxdFY?p=preview)

Answer (score 15):

As of `ui-router#0.2.15` you can use `$state.go()` and send option not to update the location:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {

  var $state = $injector.get('$state');

  $state.go('404', null, {
    location: false
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfectly working with both 'otherwise' and '$stateChangeError' interception for dynamic urls.