# ui-router navigation is occurring twice under certain conditions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a `UI-Router` site with the following states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('order', {
        url: '/order/:serviceId',
        abstract:true,
        controller: 'OrderController'
    })
    .state('order.index', {
        url:'',
        controller: 'order-IndexController'
    })
    .state('order.settings', {
        url:'',
        controller: 'order-SettingsController'
    })
```

Where my two states do NOT have a url set, meaning they should only be reachable through interaction with the application.  However the `order.index` state is automatically loaded by default because of the order in which I have defined the states.

I am noticing that trying to do a `ui-sref="^.order.settings"` or `$state.go("^.order.settings")` then `ui-router` first navigates to the `order.settings` state and then it immediately navigates to the `order.index` state (default state).  I think this is happening because the url changing is causing a second navigation to occur and since the `state.url == ''` for both, it automatically defaults to the `order.index` state...

I tested this out by setting the `{location: false}` object in the `$state.go('^order.settings', null, {location:false})`. This caused the correct state to load (order.settings), but the url did not change. Therefore I think the url changing is triggering a second navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd understand, can imagine, that you do not like my answer, but:

> **DO NOT use two non-abstract states with same url defintion**

This is not *expected*, therefore hardly supported:

```
.state('order.index', {
    url:'',                // the same url ...
    ...
})
.state('order.settings', {
    url:'',                // .. used twice
    ...
})
```

And while the `UI-Router` is really **not requiring url** definition at all (see [How not to change url when show 404 error page with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23298021/1679310)), that does not imply, that 2 url could be defined same. In such case, the first will always be evaluated, unless some special actions are used...

I would strongly sugest, provide one of *(non default)* state with some special *url*

```
.state('order.settings', {
    url:'/settings',       // ALWAYS clearly defined
    ...
})
```

Comment: Is there any built in way through ui-router to achieve the functionality I am looking for then?  I would prefer not to have a url change when these 2 states are active. Should I use basic AngularJS directives to achieve this instead? I was hoping it could be made state-based\

Comment: I am trying to explicitly say: "there is NO built in way through ui-router", because that is not expecte, not intended by state machine. States should be unique, by their url *(or in some cases do not use url at all)*. I thought you won't love my answer... sorry

Comment: Sorry I just did not fully understand what you were trying to say.  I figured this scenario is needed frequently (App in App type of design) where you wanted state-like navigation and browser history

Comment: *Wish to have "the answer"...*, enjoy the `UI-Router` anyhow. It is bloody fantastic tool ;)

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1573  -- one-to-one mappings between states and URLs will fix this.  double transitions are caused when the mapping is not one-to-one.  I believe 0.2.13 release should allow you to use $state.go() to states which match multiple URLs.  However, a browser refresh will not necessarily map back to the state you .go()'d to.