# Why does adding a url key to the state object cause a nested view NOT to display?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My index.html has a ui-view where I display greeting.html, and greeting.html has a ui-view where I am trying to display greeting.planet.html:

greeting.planet.html:

```
<div>world!</div>
```

greeting.html:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div ui-view></div>  #NESTED VIEW HERE************
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">  #APP DIRECTIVE HERE************

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">  #MainCtrl CONTROLLER HERE*********

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Test App</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div ui-view></div>   #NESTED VIEW HERE**********
  </div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.11/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:4444/index.html`, the following code succeeds in displaying the nested views:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ['ui.router']);

app.config([
'$urlRouterProvider',
'$stateProvider',
function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('greeting');

  $stateProvider
    .state('greeting', {
      //url: '/greeting',
      templateUrl: 'greeting.html'
    })

    .state('greeting.planet', {
      //url: '/planet',
      templateUrl: 'greeting.planet.html'
    });

}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$state', function($state) {
  $state.transitionTo('greeting.planet');
}]);
```

But if I uncomment the url keys in the states, then greeting.planet.html doesn't display. Why?

Comment: I believe that every state should have "url" except parent state. Because using that URL only, router getting template and put it in view.

Comment: @Asik, Thanks for taking a look.  What do you think about this: 1) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-routing-for-nested-states and this: 2) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state

Comment: ...and this: `Routing was not an afterthought to the state mechanics, but was figured into the design from the beginning (all while keeping states separate from url routing)`  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-routing-for-nested-states  If url routing is separate from states, how can adding a url to a state break the code?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLeuV1gl7bhKJFVbfzfC?p=preview), which uses your state defintions - with url:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('greeting', {
      url: '/greeting',
      templateUrl: 'greeting.html'
    })

    .state('greeting.planet', {
      url: '/planet',
      templateUrl: 'greeting.planet.html'
    });
```

and it is working. check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLeuV1gl7bhKJFVbfzfC?p=preview)

What is important to mention, I used the latest [version of to UI-Router 0.2.13](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases) *(fixes some issues, simply always use the latest)*

I also removed the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('greeting');` - redundant setting. It should navigate to default url, not a state name. So it would work with `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/greeting');` ... but default navigation is in your example done inside of *MainCtrl*... Anyway, this setting is useful, to handle any unintended state... do not forget to pass the url to existing state

EXTEND: Based on the comments, I created even more "similar" [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rXLJN8hWZXBXdDjaLxiC?p=preview)

The most important changes are: **angular 1.3** and **ui-router 0.2.13**

```
<script data-require="angular.js@*" 
     data-semver="1.3.1" 
     src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="ui-router.js"></script> // 0.2.13
```

And also, used explicit redirection: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/greeting/planet');`

Comment: Your code works with ui-router 0.2.11...but your code isn't my code.

Comment: And that means? Or just a note?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why my code doesn't work.  Your explanation seemed to be that I'm using a broken version of ui-router, but my code doesn't work with version 0.2.13 either.

Comment: I am trying to say: I created a plunker, which I intended to be as much the same as yours as possible. To show you, that make UI-Router running is not so difficult. It could be tricky, but at the end, it is not. I tried to point out, that with angular 1.3, only version 0.2.12+ is working. 0.2.11 is not working with 1.3. So now, if you still have problems, and can you reveal to me what is wrong... glad to assist...

Comment: I followed your snippets even more, and created/updated plunker to be as much as yours... http://plnkr.co/edit/rXLJN8hWZXBXdDjaLxiC?p=preview. Hope now it could help you. Good luck with UI-Router

Comment: Ahem.  Your new plunker does not display `Hello world!`, so it is not working correctly.  If I comment out the urls in the states, then it works correctly.  My question is: why does specifying a url in a state affect which states are active?  Based on what I read at the links in my comment under my question, I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: I do notice that what @Asik said seems to be true for ui-router version 0.2.13, namely that if I comment out the url in just the parent state, then the code displays `Hello world!`.  However, there is nothing in the docs at the links I posted that mentions anything about that.  In fact, the examples use urls for both the parent and child states.

Comment: Sorry I missed essential fix of your code: `otherwise`. It should be set to some existing state's url ... I selected the '/greeting/planet'. Now plunker is working. And: you are overcomplicating your searching... UI-Router is simple but powrful tool. Check my plunker you should see that it is not complicated... Finally, state does not have to have url (but it is extreme, and I would not suggest that) check example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25591908/1679310