# tell ui-router to not change location on state defintion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In ui-router, when you call state.go, you can define options to prevent the location from changing by passing `{location:false}`.  However, how do I define a state using `$stateProvider.state` so it doesn't change the location?  I've defined a rule for custom URL handling, but now it is changing the location value.

I have `foo` state -

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('foo', {
      url: '/foo'
      templateUrl: '',
      controller: function($scope) {
        console.log('made it!');
      }
    });
```

I have a custom rule -

```
   $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
     // some logic
     return '/foo';
   });
```

This works exactly how I want it to except that is changes the location and appends `#/foo` to the location.  I don't want it appended.

Comment: Have you tried to define such state without `url`? Such state is accessible via $state.go, but will not change url...

Comment: @RadimKöhler without a URL, it never resolves; let me post code

Comment: Please, check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/23298021/1679310, including working plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQ5arS1dClgM5E0QmSZF?p=preview). It is extended version of the solution presented here: [How not to change url when show 404 error page with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23298021/1679310)

There is a snippet of code, which should show how to use "foo" state without *url* change.

Firstly, there is our rule, which will redirect to `'foo'` state - just in case if the `/home` is passed as url *(an example of decision)*

```
  $urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {

    if ($location.path() == !"/home") {
      return false;
    }
    var $state = $injector.get("$state");
    // move to state, but do not change url
    $state.go("foo", {
      location: false
    })
    return true;
  });
```

Here are our example states, which do have url setting

```
  // States
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    })
    .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    })
    .state('parent.child', {
      url: "/child",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
    })
```

Foo does not have url

```
    .state('foo', {
      //url: '/foo',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    });
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQ5arS1dClgM5E0QmSZF?p=preview)