# how to pass the query parameter with the othwerwise function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Given the following javascript:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('search', {
    url: '/search?query',
})   
;

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("search");
```

When I access the page

```
base_url?query=x
```

I get redirected to

> base_url/search

but the query parameter gets lost.

Is there a way to pass the query parameter with the otherwise function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgGYfaE9bwPuwHUsBWAo?p=preview)

The UI-Router has native solution here.

> The `otherwise` does not have to be the "url" string, it could be a function.

Check it in action in this Q & A:

[How not to change url when show 404 error page with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23298021/1679310)

The code could be like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
    var state = $injector.get('$state');
    state.go("search", $location.search()); // here we get { query: ... }
    return $location.path();
});
```

The `$location.search()` will give us params object, which could be like: `{ query: ... }`. We take it and redirect to state search with this params...

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgGYfaE9bwPuwHUsBWAo?p=preview)

Comment: It does not work for me with html5mode enabled. Also in the plunkr it is commented out. May you please bring an example with html5enabled on? I get sort of redirected twice. I printed console.log($location,$location.path(), $location.search());. The first time i get  "/" Object {vid: "Auto1"} and then  "/" Object {}

Comment: *I am not fan or user of html 5 mode,* but here you are the adjusted version: http://plnkr.co/edit/yrfOXMeaCJEKt08ihw00?p=preview. In a nutshell: Do not forget to include proper "absolute" url... because we are not living in safe are, doing safe routing after hash #...

Comment: I think that there is no need to write return $location.path();. This triggers an additional state redirect while we issued already a state redirect with the state.go function.

Comment: I appended some console log, to this fork http://plnkr.co/edit/uLFCZHkiUOHk4STvTux6?p=preview to show that my plunker should be working well. Most importantly, as the [doc saysg(http://stackoverflow.com/a/25591908/1679310):  otherwise must be: *The url path you want to redirect to or a function rule that returns the url path.* so we have to (shuold) return that... Hope it helps a bit...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to grab injector and $state.go, not at all. The argument to `otherwise` method can be a URL path, which can **contain parameters in it**.

So in your particular case, following code can lead you to **base_url/search?query=x**

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/search?query=x");
```

Alternatively, the argument can be a function that returns a URL path. If you are not sure what URL parameters it could have, you just need to get the parameters from `$location` then format to the URL-like string and return it.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
    var params = $location.search()

    // format params to 'p1=v1&p2=v2' style
    var formatted = Object.keys(params).map(function(key) {
        return key + '=' + params[key]
    }).join('&')

    return '/search?' + formatted
});
```