# How To Autoload ui-view on nested views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have code like this

```
<a ui-sref="nested.something">something</a>
<div ui-view="nested.something"></div>
```

how to load ui-view without click ui-sref ?

Comment: Have you seen `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/something');`? - doc http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_otherwise

Comment: that's code is on my nested views, how can i use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/something'); ?

Comment: Honestly, how would one know that this code is on your nested view? Should not you provide a bit more details? Even a plunker would help. Solution with `UI-Router` could at the end be very simple...

Comment: Alternatively, have the child state's URL be `url: ''`. It should load with the parent

Comment: @DonnyGunawan extended answer with more details and more examples. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXTEND** - related to this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FYWLsLgEPzPWQBHeyn2F) provided by OP in the comments above

The state definition is:

```
.state('store', {
    views: {
      'store': {
        templateUrl: 'store.html'
      }
    }
})
  
.state('store.detail', {
    views: {
      'store_detail': {
        templateUrl: 'store_detail.html'
      }
    }
})
```

Then in this [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3GEPAuyqFWkUu0dmWTDI?p=preview) we can see that this would do the job

```
//$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/store');
  
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
   var state = $injector.get('$state');
   state.go('store.detail');
   return $location.path();
});
```

Reason? states do not have defined url. Which is a bit weird. So, I would honestly rather suggested to do it like this  ([the link to such plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jNFSZt0X0mAWdjsDnT9x?p=preview)):

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/store/detail');
  //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
  //   var state = $injector.get('$state');
  //   state.go('store.detail');
  //   return $location.path();
  //});
  
  $stateProvider
  
  .state('store', {
    url: '/store',
    views: {
      'store': {
        templateUrl: 'store.html'
      }
    }
  })
  
  .state('store.detail', {
    url: '/detail',
    views: {
      'store_detail': {
        templateUrl: 'store_detail.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jNFSZt0X0mAWdjsDnT9x?p=preview)

**ORIGINAL**

We can use the `.otherwise(rule)` of `$urlRouterProvider`, documented [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_otherwise)

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/parent/child');
```

As the doc says:

> **`otherwise(rule)`**
>
> Defines a path that is used when an invalid route is requested.

So, this could be used for some default - start up "redirection"

The `.otherwise()` could be even a function, like shown here:

[How not to change url when show 404 error page with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23298021/1679310)

which takes '$injector', '$location' and can do even much more magic *(on invalid or startup path)*

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
   var state = $injector.get('$state');
   state.go('404');
   return $location.path();
});
```

ALSO, if we want to fill in some more details into some **nested viesw**, we can do it by defining multi-named views:

```
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child",
      views: {
        '' : {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.child.html',
          controller: 'ChildCtrl',
        },
        'nested.something@parent.child' : {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.something.html',
        },
      }
  })
```

So, if the tpl.child.html will have this anchor/target:

```
<i>place for nested something:</i>
<div ui-view="nested.something"></div>
```

it will be filled with the *tpl.something.html* content

Check it [in action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qUvTf5hZ3O3dr4Bk1xAp?p=preview)

Comment: what i mean is, when i click ui-sref="store" i want to load ui-view="store" and ui-view="store_detail" too, i want to load both when i click ui-sref="store"

^_^ thx i can do it now ^_^
http://plnkr.co/edit/vKAbvHrtuHIBKkyNCbtq?p=preview