# Conditional "otherwise" routing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm familiar with the `"$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('{route here}')"` syntax in angular to use as catch all in Angular UI-Router.

What I'm wondering is - is there a way to do conditional "otherwise" routing based on the parent state of when the route is entered incorrectly?

For instance, suppose that I have the following configuration:

```
$stateProvider
.state('core', {configuration here})
.state('core.page1', {configuration here...})
.state('dashboard', {configuration here})
.state('dashboard.page1', {configuration here})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/core/page1');
```

What I'd like to have happen is that anytime a route is entered in that has **`"/core/{route here}"`**,
if it doesn't match any of the current states, to route back to **'/core/page1'**,
and anytime a route is entered that has **`"/dashboard/{route here}"`** that doesn't match any of the current states, to route back to **`"/dashboard/page1"`**.

Anyone have experience doing this, or an idea of how I could accomplish it? Is there anything built in to Angular that allows for this type of behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As shown here

#### [How not to change url when show 404 error page with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23298021/1679310)

The **`.otherwise()`** does not have to be a string (url)... it could be a smart decision maker:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
   var state = $injector.get('$state');
   if(....)
     state.go('core');
   else(...)
     state.go('dashboard');
   ...
   return $location.path();
});
```

The doc:

[$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(rule)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_otherwise)

> Defines a path that is used when an invalid route is requested.
>
> **string** - The url path you want to redirect to or a function rule that returns the url path.
> The **function** version is passed two params: $injector and $location services, and must return a url string.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the rapid response. This looks exactly like what I'm looking for! Just as an FYI - the link you listed ($urlRouterProvider.otherwise(rule)) isn't working.

Comment: You were right... thanks. I fixed the link to get right to the DOC ;)