# How to get $urlRouterProvider.otherwise to redirect to a state instead of a path?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I want to redirect to a state instead of a path, can't quite figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar Q & A:

#### [How not to change url when show 404 error page with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23298021/1679310)

We can get injector and ask for a `$state`

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
   var state = $injector.get('$state');
   state.go('404');
   return $location.path();
});
```

[see that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23298021/1679310) for a working plunker

Answer (score 1):

The .otherwise() does not have to be a string (url) or a state, it could be a smart decision maker:

You can get the desired result by following code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
$injector.invoke(['$state', function($state) {
$state.go('yourState');
}]);
});
```